# Prevent iPhone from zooming in when clicking text box?

Tags: android, html, ios, css, iphone

I while back ago *(like 1.5y ago)* I created an bitcoin alarm web app and at that time it worked fine, but now when I check it I noticed an issue, when I click the textbox the iPhone zooms in on the textbox and then everything gets stuck zoomed in.

**Is there a way to prevent it from zooming in?**

I'm testing on an iPhone 6 on ios 9, it should also work on iPad, android and PC etc, if someone that have an android / or another IOS and want to test if those also have the same issue, or if its just ios 9/or iPhone 6

click the link from the device you want

**[Launch the app here:](http://www.patan77.com/btcalarm/)** *(click the link from the device you want use it on)*

or go to *[www.patan77.com/btcalarm](http://www.patan77.com/btcalarm)*

I am using this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,minimal-ui, user-scalable=0, width=device-width, height=device-height"/>
```

[image]

**

### Broken/zoomed in issue:

**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

iOS automatically zooms in on a text input's field if the font-size is below 16px. If you set the font-size to 16px or larger it won't zoom in.

iOS does this to ensure the content is legible.

I think the reason you can't zoom out once it focuses is because of your meta tag. Try removing `user-scalable=0`.